# Let Facebook crawler see page as an authenticated user?

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-graph-api, meta-tags

Facebook's crawler isn't getting my og meta data because php first requires FB authentication. Is there a way to have FB's crawlers view the web page as the user who took the custom action (share etc)? Or, in lieu of that, is there any other way to give FB the meta data while still using custom actions?

Answer (score 1):

You have to return the metadata to Facebook's crawler for that URL if you want it to work correctly, even if there's no other actual content on the page, and even if other browsers hitting that URL receive a HTTP 401 or a redirect.

If you can't make an exception for that endpoint so that Facebook's crawler can reach the metdata, you'd have to setup a new, unauthenticated endpoint specifically to serve the meta tags to Facebook, and redirect any other traffic into your main site

Comment: As my current temporary solution, I've got all the meta data I need passed to FB as params, so that when fb's crawler hits the site, I can get the data to put into the meta tags. This just feels like a really ugly solution though. To be sure, are you saying that it's impossible for FB's crawler to see the page as an authenticated user (ie, the user doing the sharing)?

Comment: Yes - the facebook crawler is effectively a logged-out user, otherwise you could bypass a site's authentication by pretending to be the Facebook crawler

Comment: Thanks. One more follow-up question: is it not possible to provide all the meta data in the post to FB up front? This could alleviate the dependency on the crawler...

Comment: No, it needs to be on the URL, and the URL needs to remain accessible

Comment: guys when you resolve something its necessary to post the solution here so others can benefit from it, unlike your discussion which is of no use for anyone else. After all this is a public platform :)

Comment: Thanks for commenting on this six year old answer about a feature Facebook doesn't even have any more except for link sharing :)